# Parse js/css as a PHP file using htaccess

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess

Hi I have been trying so hard to do the following on htaccess but it does not seem to work.

can someone out there help me?

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .js`

I tried the php4,php5 version all the things I could find on google but I had no luck.

what have I missed?

in my file.js

are the following...

```
<?php 

$(document).ready();//jquery/javascript
?>
```

I am expect a php fatal error but I see exactly the above as plain text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .js
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: You have to do this to get PHP To process your .js files, however, you don't need to use AddHandler inside a <FilesMatch> directive, but you would if you were using SetHandler.  But when you use this handler, the MIME type of the response will default to text/html, and I don't think this can be overridden in .htaccess, which means you'll need to (re)set the MIME type in PHP, as per @Steve's answer.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to do this using just .htaccess configuration (who wants to set the headers in *every* PHP file?):

```
<FilesMatch "\.css$">
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
  Header set Content-type "text/css"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.js$">
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
  Header set Content-type "application/javascript"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: If you're getting a 500 Internal Server Error with the Header line, make sure you have mod_headers enabled in your apache config. Thanks Lee!

Answer (score 2):

If I am correct, your PHP JS file has to be served with a header of content-type: application/x-javascript, otherwise it is not interpreted as JS.

Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");

Comment: `<?php 
header("content-type: application/x-javascript");` thats my output now... It needs to be processed as a php file type first then have the ability to add the content type no ?

Comment: I don't think many browsers care what the content type of JavaScript files are, but some assume if a CSS file is text/html, then it's probably a fancy 404 and nothing will be processed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make PHP work in Javascript files you can simply rename the Javascript to `javascript_file.js.php` and have PHP work inside of that.

You will have no problem including that into your page.

`

Comment: I know thats best, however, on my notpad++ i'd like to have the highlighters on and not black and white :)

Comment: Can you still include using `<script src="..."></script>`? Or would you have to use php to include?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you're not configured to allow the use of an .htaccess file.

You can check this in your httpd.conf.

You want to ensure that `AllowOverride` is set to `All`

eg

from

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Satisfy all
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Satisfy all
</Directory>
```

Comment: .htaccess works as I have tested with `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` and some other bits there (which I tried removing them all, but the `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .js`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about .htaccess but I do believe part the solution to your problem is to move the jQuery outside of the php tags as so:

```
<?php

?>
</script>
    $(document).ready();
<script>
```

your file is going to be parsed as any other php file, so your javascript will execute as normal, inside of javascript tags.

if you would like to include php variables inside your javascript just do as so:

```
<?php
    $time=time();
?>

    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function(){
            $("SPAN").text("<? echo $time; ?>");
        });
    </script>
    <SPAN></SPAN>
```

the above code will return the current epoch timestamp inside of the SPAN element