# Parse CSS file as PHP

Tags: php, apache

So, I moved into a new host. I was using some code in my htaccess to parse css files as PHP. But in this new host, it didn't work. I googled and googled and tried every code I find. All single of them didn't work. Here's some of codes I've tried:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .css
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .css
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .css
AddType application/x-httpd-php .css
```

My PHP version is 5.3.22 and my webhost is using Linux. But they all didn't work. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse js/css as a PHP file using htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722375/parse-js-css-as-a-php-file-using-htaccess)

Comment: Curiosity grabbed me: What's the reason behind parsing CSS as PHP? I don't quite get it. Enlighten me.

Comment: There's a PHP code that compresses the css file @Fred

Comment: @MarioErmando Hm... interesting. I'm going to have to look into that; including "Good 'ol Google" [**GoG**](http://www.google.com) cheers

Comment: @MarioErmando Have you tried the [**answer here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10722444/1415724), by replacing `js` with `css`?

Comment: Yep, still doesn't work. :( @Fred

Comment: @MarioErmando Check what the differences are from your previous web host, if possible. Might be something in an `.ini` file, something that's pre-configured with the new service. Hard to tell, could be a number of reasons.

Comment: If you're going for a dynamic stylesheet, why can't you reference a .php file as your stylesheet and then use `header('Content-type: text/css');` within that file? I've seen that done many times.

Answer (score 2):

From [Parse js/css as a PHP file using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722375/parse-js-css-as-a-php-file-using-htaccess)

You should just need to add this to your htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.css$">
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
  Header set Content-type "text/css"
</FilesMatch>
```

If you're getting a 500 Internal Server Error with the Header line, make sure you have mod_headers enabled in your apache config, if mod_headers is not installed and your provider will not install/enable it, you will need to rename your css file to .php and add into your new php file

```
header("Content-type: text/css");
```

Comment: It gives 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: If you're getting a 500 Internal Server Error with the Header line, make sure you have mod_headers enabled in your apache config, if it isnt installed or enabled, your out of luck and have to rename to .php

Answer (score 2):

I just tried making a folder called "style.css" and put a file inside called "index.php" and it works in chrome!

Of course you need to put `header("Content-type: text/css");` in the php file and I'm not sure how well it works in other browsers or email clients