# Use CakePHP Configuration in CSS File

Tags: php, css, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Is it possible to access the configuration from CakePHP(3.x) in a CSS file?

For example I would like to define a general background color in the CakePHP configuration file and use it in multiple CSS definitions.

I am aware of CSS preprocessors like "LESS" or "SASS" but this isn't suited for our needs.

Has anybody a good idea or workaround for this?

Comment: Have you already seen this [site](http://miljenkobarbir.com/using-php-to-generate-css/)?

Answer (score 0):

CSS files **are not** parsed by PHP.

You have 3 choices:

1) generate and write a css file with the rules you need (on the fly or better with any cache logic)

2) old fashion school, create different css and call the one you need on a case by case situation.

3) tell PHP to parse CSS files, there are several ways to do that like [using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722375/parse-js-css-as-a-php-file-using-htaccess)