# how to add javascript code in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to add script code in php but it giving error on this line

```
$a=echo "document.getElementById('t1').value;";
```

of unexpected use of ECHO! Can any one help???

```
<?php
    echo "<script>";
    $a=echo "document.getElementById('t1').value;";


    if($_session['user']==$a) {
        echo 'function fun() {
            document.write("welcom");
        }';
    }

    echo "</script>";
?>
```

Comment: just get rid of the `$a=`

Comment: also, echo isn't the only way to write output.  You can stop php with `?>` and write out html/css/script and then start php again with `<?php`

Comment: Check these answers - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596218/how-to-write-javascript-code-inside-php
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471945/how-can-you-use-php-in-a-javascript-function

These will help you

Comment: Syntax problems aside, I think you're trying to mix up code that runs on the server and code that runs on the client. Your PHP code can generate and return some Javascript to the browser, but it can't interact with javascript in the way you appear to be attempting.

Comment: Any values that you want sent from Javascript (website user's computer) to PHP (web server) _must_ be done by a HTTP request.  Either post a form, use a querystring or use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is from `$a=echo` because `echo` is a php function.

The correct syntax is:

```
<?php
$a= "document.getElementById('t1').value;";
echo "<script>";
echo $a;
if($_session['user']==$a) {
    echo 'document.write("welcom");';
}
echo "</script>";
?>
```

Comment: `if($_session['user']=="document.getElementById('t1').value;")` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score -1):

You cant use echo function in variable. You can echo variable only and there are 2 ways, how to achieve this:

**1)** you can save the content into variable via:

```
$a = "document.getElementById('t1').value;";
```

and somewhere in your code where you will need it you can echo the content of `$a` variable via: `echo $a;`

**2)** you can echo the content of your variable in the concrete line:

```
echo "document.getElementById('t1').value;";
```

Comment: `if($_session['user']=="document.getElementById('t1').value;")` doesn't make any sense. The OP is trying to compare the *return value* of a JavaScript expression with a PHP string.

Comment: but he asked, why he has got unexpected use of ECHO, so I write him this explanation for his question

Comment: You're focusing too much on the literal question title and ignoring the underlying problem that is demonstrated by the code example provided in it.

Comment: The main problem in this question is, that he trying pass the JS variable into PHP I think. But now he asked, why the posted code showing him error, this is explained in my answer. Now, when he will fix the error, he will find, that the code not workin and can create a new question with title like: "I am trying to pass JS variable into my PHP code and its not workin" ....